# Function approximation Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, mathematical-optimization, approximation

I am trying to create a neural network in Tensorflow that approximates a sine function. I have found some examples of universal function approximators but I am not fully understanding the code and, since I am quite new with Tensorflow, I would like to code it myself to understand every step.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Create the arrays x and y that contains the inputs and the outputs of the function to approximate
x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/1000).reshape((1000,1))
y = np.sin(x)
# plt.plot(x,y)
# plt.show()

# Define the number of nodes
n_nodes_hl1 = 100
n_nodes_hl2 = 100

# Define the number of outputs and the learn rate
n_classes = 1
learn_rate = 0.1

# Define input / output placeholders
x_ph = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 1])
y_ph = tf.placeholder('float')


# Routine to compute the neural network (2 hidden layers)
def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_classes])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}


    # (input_data * weights) + biases
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'])

    return output


# Routine to train the neural network
def train_neural_network(x_ph):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x_ph)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction - y_ph))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(cost)

    # cycles feed forward + backprop
    hm_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # Train in each epoch with the whole data
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x_ph: x, y_ph: y})
            epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y_ph, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy;', accuracy.eval({x_ph: x, y_ph: x}))


# Train network
train_neural_network(x_ph)
```

If you run that program you will see how the loss diverges and I don't know why it behaves like that. Could anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

@AIdream was right about `initial learning rate convergence issue` in general. But even with a `lean_rate=1.0e-9` and `10000 epochs`, the error is still large means the issue is something else.

---

**Debugging the problem**

Running the above code, gives:

```
Epoch 0 completed out of 10 loss: 61437.30859375
Epoch 1 completed out of 10 loss: 1.2855042406744022e+21
Epoch 2 completed out of 10 loss: inf
Epoch 3 completed out of 10 loss: nan
```

The above code tries to approximate a `sin function` within a range  `(0, 2*pi)`. Since the labels(outputs) is going to be `(-1,1)`, the higher error indicates a large value being initialized for weights. Changing the weights to have a smaller initialized value (`stddev=0.01`), leads to:

```
Epoch 0 completed out of 10 loss: 0.5000443458557129
Epoch 1 completed out of 10 loss: 0.4999848008155823
Epoch 2 completed out of 10 loss: 0.49993154406547546
Epoch 3 completed out of 10 loss: 0.4998819828033447
```

The loss converged really fast, but checking the prediction it seems the inputs are all getting mapped to zero.

[image]

The problem is because the inputs in the above code are given as a `single batch` and not as `mini batches`. `Batch gradient decent` can lead to a local minimum problem and once it reaches the local minimum it cannot come out of it. `Mini batch` avoids this problem, as the gradients computed on batches are noisy and can get you out of the local minimums. With those changes leads to:

```
Epoch 0 completed out of 100 loss: 456.28773515997455
Epoch 10 completed out of 100 loss: 6.713319106237066
Epoch 20 completed out of 100 loss: 0.24847120749460316
Epoch 30 completed out of 100 loss: 0.09907744570556076
```

[image]

---

The above steps can be reproduced by downloading the source from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lvBR1BinCtTP7sCTaCIzjuJB4qx76hAE).

Answer (score 5):

Your initial learning rate for the gradient descent is just too big for it to converge toward a minima (see for instance this other thread about gradient descent and learning rate values: ["Gradient descent explodes if learning rate is too large"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315664/gradient-descent-explodes-if-learning-rate-is-too-large)).

Just replace its value with e.g. `learn_rate = 1.0e-9` here and your network will converge.

Trace:

```
Epoch 0 completed out of 10000 loss: 8512.4736328125
Epoch 1 completed out of 10000 loss: 8508.4677734375
...
Epoch 201 completed out of 10000 loss: 7743.56396484375
Epoch 202 completed out of 10000 loss: 7739.92431640625
...
Epoch 7000 completed out of 10000 loss: 382.22601318359375
Epoch 7001 completed out of 10000 loss: 382.08026123046875
...
Epoch 9998 completed out of 10000 loss: 147.459716796875
Epoch 9999 completed out of 10000 loss: 147.4239501953125
...
```